# Redirect to the beginning page unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query to log a user into my React application, and when the user clicks the "logout" button, it should redirect to the home page, `"/"`. However, when I click "logout" button, the page doesn't redirect to the home page.

In my Layout.jsx, I use `useEffect` hook to check whether the mutation succeeded

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [sendLogout, { isLoading, isSuccess, isError, error }] =
  useSendLogoutMutation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess) {
    console.log("success");
    navigate("/");
  }
}, [isSuccess, navigate]);
```

In my authApiSlice.js, when I comment out `dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());`, the `isSuccess` value in the code above works, however, if I add the code `dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());`, it doesn't work again.

```js
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";
import { logOut } from "./authSlice";

export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: "/auth",
        method: "POST",
        body: { ...credentials },
      }),
    }),
    sendLogout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/auth/logout",
        method: "POST",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          //   console.log(data);
          dispatch(logOut());
          dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
    }),
    refresh: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/auth/refresh",
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useLoginMutation,
  useSendLogoutMutation,
  useRefreshMutation
} = authApiSlice;
```

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you did anything overtly *wrong*, per se, but resetting the API slice state during a mutation request processing probably isn't the best thing to do since this appears to clear in-flight requests and their associated metadata.

That said, you don't need to wait for the mutation endpoint to complete and trigger the component using the `useSendLogoutMutation` to rerender so the mutation results are accessible, the `sendLogout` trigger function returns a Promise that be used to run additional logic *after* a successful mutation call. I suspect this could work for you here.

See [useMutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#signature-1) signature:

> ```
> type UseMutation = (
>   options?: UseMutationStateOptions
> ) => [UseMutationTrigger, UseMutationResult | SelectedUseMutationResult]
> ```

> ```
> type UseMutationTrigger<T> = (arg: any) => Promise<
>   { data: T } | { error: BaseQueryError | SerializedError }
> > & {
>   requestId: string // A string generated by RTK Query
>   abort: () => void // A method to cancel the mutation promise
>   unwrap: () => Promise<T> // A method to unwrap the mutation call and provide the raw response/error
>   reset: () => void // A method to manually unsubscribe from the mutation call and reset the result to the uninitialized state
> }
> ```

Invoke the `sendLogout` trigger function and `await` its unwrapped result.

Example:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [
  sendLogout,
  { isLoading, isError, error }
] = useSendLogoutMutation();

...

const logoutHandler = async () => {
  try {
    await sendLogout().unwrap(); // <-- trigger mutation and await success

    // Success, redirect to home
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore any thrown errors or Promise rejections
  }
};

...
```

If there's still an issue with resetting the API slice from within the `sendLogout` endpoint then my suggestion would be to reset it *after* the mutation succeeds. Similar to above.

```js
...
sendLogout: builder.mutation({
  query: () => ({
    url: "/auth/logout",
    method: "POST",
  }),
  async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
      dispatch(logOut());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
}),
...
```

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [
  sendLogout,
  { isLoading, isError, error }
] = useSendLogoutMutation();

...

const logoutHandler = async () => {
  try {
    await sendLogout().unwrap();

    // Success, reset API state and redirect to home
    dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState()); // <-- reset after success
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore any thrown errors or Promise rejections
  }
};

...
```

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion works! To summarize, using the result from the mutation to re-render isn't a good practice, right?

Comment: @Tik1993 I don't consider it "not a good practice". It's a general use case that you trigger a mutation and would like to display a loading indicator and other UI based on the mutation status. Like I said though, resetting the API cache state in the middle of one of these operations was likely the problem, not trying to use the result in the UI component.

Comment: @Tik1993 Sometimes you don't care about "intermediate" results, but want to chain additional logic from the dispatched action. RTKQ allows for either. Instead of a complicated series of query/mutation-useEffect hook pairings you can simply Promise-chain or `async/await` a series of triggered mutations/queries. I hope this makes sense.